# Centralize text in a button with icon (CSS)

Tags: html, css, button, center

I have 2 buttons, each one with icon and a text.
The problem is that the text goes down and I want it to be on the same level. How can I do it without changing the icon's size?

[image]

HTML + CSS code:

```css
.cv-container button
{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
    border-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="cv-container">
                    <a href="Files/Tsahi Barshavsky - CV.docx" style="margin-right: 5px;" download>
                        <button><img src="Images/doc.svg">Resume - DOC version</button>
                    </a>
                    <a href="Files/Tsahi Barshavsky - CV.pdf" style="margin-left: 5px;" download>
                        <button><img src="Images/pdf.svg">Resume - PDF version</button>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest alteration I'd suggest is to add `line-height` as a property with the same value as `height`. See below.

```css
.cv-container button
{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
    border-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="cv-container">
  <a href="Files/Tsahi Barshavsky - CV.docx" style="margin-right: 5px;" download>
    <button><img src="Images/doc.svg">Resume - DOC version</button>
  </a>
  <a href="Files/Tsahi Barshavsky - CV.pdf" style="margin-left: 5px;" download>
    <button><img src="Images/pdf.svg">Resume - PDF version</button>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `flex` properties to solve this. There are other methods also, but this one is simple.

```css
.cv-container button
{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
    border-color: black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.cv-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="cv-container">
      <a href="Files/Tsahi Barshavsky - CV.docx" style="margin-right: 5px;" download>
           <button><img src="Images/doc.svg">Resume - DOC version</button>
      </a>
      <a href="Files/Tsahi Barshavsky - CV.pdf" style="margin-left: 5px;" download>
           <button><img src="Images/pdf.svg">Resume - PDF version</button>
      </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues.